# How do I get current file position during sequential read in Java?

Tags: java, file, position

I need to be able to know when I have read the last record from a file (or, to put it another way, I need to know when the *next* read will return EOF).  I'd prefer to determine this by obtaining the current file position, rather than trying to read ahead and maintain a 1-deep queue.

The following demonstrates the problem I'm having: unfortunately, it turns out that myFileChannel.position() appears to be telling me the offset to the first position *that hasn't been read into the **buffer***.  For example, after the first readline(), position() returns 8192.

Is there a method by which I can obtain the offset of the first character that hasn't been consumed by readline()?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public final class FilePosition {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String            myFileName = args[0];
        File              myFile; 
        FileInputStream   myInputStream;
        InputStreamReader myInputStreamReader; 
        FileChannel       myFileChannel;
        BufferedReader    myBufferedReader;
        long              myFileSize;
        long              myFilePosition;

        String absDirPath = "/Users/chap/Documents/workspace/FilePosition/bin/";
        myFileName = args[0];

        try {
            myFile              = new File(absDirPath + myFileName);
            myInputStream       = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            myInputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(myInputStream);
            myBufferedReader    = new BufferedReader(myInputStreamReader);

            myFileChannel = myInputStream.getChannel();
            myFileSize    = myFileChannel.size();

            String inputLine = "";
            while (inputLine != null) {
                inputLine = myBufferedReader.readLine();
                // myFilePosition = ?
                myFilePosition = myFileChannel.position();
                say(inputLine + "   Size=" + myFileSize + ", Pos=" + myFilePosition);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            say("Exception caught opening file " + 
                    myFileName + ": " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
    }

    private static void say(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like, getting the size of the entire file in advance. And then as you read it (may be line-by-line), compute how much you have done. Not sure if its feasible to you, just a thought.

Comment: I've got the size of the entire file, using myFileChannel.size() .. (unless there turn out to be any surprises about what *that* is).  Keeping a running tally of the length of each input line is my fallback position; it's not ideal because of having to figure out the length of the line delimiter.